# Where am I doing wrong in downloading a file with '.CSV' format in CodeIgniter's controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and was working on downloading a file. However, I want to download a file that resides on my local machine, I am able to locate the file by providing the path, also the file gets downloaded with a `File` type, However, I want my file to be in `.csv format`

Here goes my Controller's download function:

```
public function download()
{   
        $state_id=$this->input->post('state'); // gets me the state-id from viw's dropdown
        $this->load->helper('download'); // Load download helper
        $file="C:\\Users\usernew\\Desktop\\New folder\\".$state_id.".csv";
        $filename=$state_id.'.csv';
        
    
        if (file_exists($file))
        {
                $data = file_get_contents($file);       //check file exists 
                force_download($fileName,$data);
            }
            else{
                echo"not working!";
            }    
        }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Sorry, your questions is not clear, can you try and add some detail?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ RiggsFolly thank you, I have edited the same, please consider!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `force_download()` function accepts the file name to be set and the data to insert into that file, as you have the data in that file already, you just need to download it.  so, You should use the `for_download()` function like this:

```
force_download($file,NULL);
```

This will solve your problem :)